# Space Movie with one real apple

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to remember a movie, set in space on a space ship where oxygen and water are scarce. The crew always has to control their breathing and water is in little 5x5cm2 blue pouches.  One person said he was from Venus or Mars, and one (same?) had a real apple which the others didn't think possible. That person loses the apple and cries because he never tasted apples.

They found another spaceship, but it was destroyed by a meteor (while the ship is spinning the hole from the meteor becomes visible). They got into an argument whether to go EVA and collect scattered supplies or not.

One time a micro meteor hits their ship and one crew member blocks the hole with the palm of her(?) hand while the others get a gun shaped tool and seal the hole.

The movie is darkish and ~2000 +- 5 years I guess.